# Best sketching app with line assist for android tablet using a stylus

Tags: software

Are there any good sketching apps for an Android tablet? I like the idea of sketching with a stylus however the lines usually end up looking quite shaky. The goal is to use it either real time during online lectures by sharing the screen or at least while preparing notes to be shared.

I love the speed and flexibility of freeform drawing but on the other hand would like the sketches to look a little neater without actually using primitives like line, shape etc. (e.g. in a powerpoint or visio drawing).

The goal is sketches, illustrations and flowcharts and that sort of thing. Not creative designs nor engineering drawings.  Think of the sort of drawings a typical physics or engineering professor would conventionally have drawn on the blackboard.

Any recommendations for a good app?